# Finding country by IP address

Tags: java, location, ip, country

I am using java (eclipse) for this project.
My goal is to take a small list of IP addresses from a text file and output the country of origin for each IP address.

Should I use GeoIP or is there more efficient ways of doing the above? If I were to use GeoIP does anyone have any links to an introduction for it?
Many thanks

Comment: check out the ip2ans2cc library: https://github.com/AxLabs/ip2asn2cc

Answer (score 0):

if you search google for [`ip location lookup api`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=ip%20location%20lookup) you'll find a few options you can use. First result for me is http://ip-api.com/ which is free and has an api documentation.